# How to calculate Sentiment Score of a Document

Tags: sentiment-analysis

How to determine sentiment score of an entire document??
I tried using VADER and Text-blob packages but they are only good for determining sentiment score of a sentence.

Comment: You could try Microsoft cognitive services, more specifically their text analytics / sentiment analysis tools. You can just pass in the entire block of text to that and it will give you a sentiment score.

Answer (score 0):

An idea which comes to mind for your problem is ***to split your document by sentences***, for that step you can use [NLTK text segmentation module](https://mailman.uib.no/public/corpora/2007-October/005426.html), ***calculate sentiment for each sentence*** and ***sum sentiment scores***.

Afterword, consider text to be negative if total ***score < -0.5***, and positive if ***score > 0.5***